# The Travelling Salesman Problem Using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I was looking to learn about AI and found the traveling salesman problem very interesting. I also wanted to learn about genetic algorithms, so it was a fantastic combo. The task is to find the shortest distance traveling from `id 1` to each location from the list once and returning to the starting location `id 1`

*Restriction for the problem :*

> The location `id 1` must be the starting and the ending point
>
> The maximum distance allowed is `distance <= 9000`
>
> Only max of `250000`  fitness calculation is allowed

---

**Code** :

```
import numpy as np
import random
import operator
import pandas as pd

val10 = 0
val9 = 0
class Locations:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, location):
        x_dist = abs(float(self.x) - float(location.x))
        y_dist = abs(float(self.y) - float(location.y))
        # √( (x2 − x1)^2 + (2 − 1)^2 )
        dist = np.sqrt((x_dist ** 2) + (y_dist ** 2))
        return dist

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"


class Fitness:
    def __init__(self, route):
        self.r = route
        self.dist = 0
        self.fit = 0.0

    def route_dist(self):
        if self.dist == 0:
            path_dist = 0
            for i in range(0, len(self.r)):
                from_location = self.r[i]
                to_location = None
                if i + 1 < len(self.r):
                    to_location = self.r[i+1]
                else:
                    to_location = self.r[0]

                path_dist += from_location.dist(to_location)
            self.dist = path_dist
        return self.dist

    def route_fittness(self):
        if self.fit == 0:
            self.fit = 1 / float(self.route_dist())
        global val9
        val9 = val9 + 1    
        return self.fit


def generate_route(location_list):
    route = random.sample(location_list, len(location_list))
    return route


def gen_zero_population(size, location_list):
    population = []

    for i in range(0, size):
        population.append(generate_route(location_list))
    return population


def determine_fit(population):
    result = {}
    for i in range(0, len(population)):
        result[i] = Fitness(population[i]).route_fittness()
    global val10
    val10 = val10 + 1
    return sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


def fit_proportionate_selection(top_pop, elite_size):
    result = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(top_pop), columns=["index", "Fitness"])
    df['cumulative_sum'] = df.Fitness.cumsum()
    df['Sum'] = 100*df.cumulative_sum/df.Fitness.sum()

    for i in range(0, elite_size):
        result.append(top_pop[i][0])
    for i in range(0, len(top_pop) - elite_size):
        select = 100*random.random()
        for i in range(0, len(top_pop)):
            if select <= df.iat[i, 3]:
                result.append(top_pop[i][0])
                break
    return result


def select_mating_pool(populatoin, f_p_s_result):
    mating_pool = []
    for i in range(0, len(f_p_s_result)):
        index = f_p_s_result[i]
        mating_pool.append(populatoin[index])
    return mating_pool


def ordered_crossover(p1, p2):
    child, child_p1, child_p2 = ([] for i in range(3))

    first_gene = int(random.random() * len(p1))
    sec_gene = int(random.random() * len(p2))

    start_gene = min(first_gene, sec_gene)
    end_gene = max(first_gene, sec_gene)

    for i in range(start_gene, end_gene):
        child_p1.append(p1[i])

    child_p2 = [item for item in p2 if item not in child_p1]

    child = child_p1 + child_p2
    return child


def ordered_crossover_pop(mating_pool, elite_size):
    children = []

    leng = (len(mating_pool) - (elite_size))
    pool = random.sample(mating_pool, len(mating_pool))

    for i in range(0, elite_size):
        children.append(mating_pool[i])

    for i in range(0, leng):
        var = len(mating_pool)-i - 1
        child = ordered_crossover(pool[i], pool[var])
        children.append(child)
    return children


def swap_mutation(one_location, mutation_rate):
    for i in range(len(one_location)):
        if (random.random() < mutation_rate):
            swap = int(random.random() * len(one_location))

            location1 = one_location[i]
            location2 = one_location[swap]

            one_location[i] = location2
            one_location[swap] = location1
    return one_location


def pop_mutation(population, mutation_rate):
    result = []

    for i in range(0, len(population)):
        mutaded_res = swap_mutation(population[i], mutation_rate)
        result.append(mutaded_res)
    return result


def next_gen(latest_gen, elite_size, mutation_rate):
    route_rank = determine_fit(latest_gen)
    selection = fit_proportionate_selection(route_rank, elite_size)
    mating_selection = select_mating_pool(latest_gen, selection)
    children = ordered_crossover_pop(mating_selection, elite_size)
    next_generation = pop_mutation(children, mutation_rate)
    return next_generation


def generic_algor(population, pop_size, elite_size, mutation_rate, gen):
    pop = gen_zero_population(pop_size, population)
    print("Initial distance: " + str(1 / determine_fit(pop)[0][1]))

    for i in range(0, gen):
        pop = next_gen(pop, elite_size, mutation_rate)

    print("Final distance: " + str(1 / determine_fit(pop)[0][1]))
    best_route_index = determine_fit(pop)[0][0]
    best_route = pop[best_route_index]
    print(best_route)
    return best_route


def read_file(fn):
    a = []
    with open(fn) as f:
        [next(f) for _ in range(6)]
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == 'EOF':
                break

            ID, x, y = line.split()
            a.append(Locations(x=x, y=y))
    return a


location_list = read_file(r'path_of_the_file')

population = location_list
pop_size = 100
elite_size = 40
mutation_rate = 0.001
gen = 500
generic_algor(population, pop_size, elite_size, mutation_rate, gen)

print(val10)
print(val9)
```

**Location file with `x` and `y` coordinates** :

```
|Locations
|
|52 Locations
|
|Coordinates
|
1 565.0 575.0
2 25.0 185.0
3 345.0 750.0
4 945.0 685.0
5 845.0 655.0
6 880.0 660.0
7 25.0 230.0
8 525.0 1000.0
9 580.0 1175.0
10 650.0 1130.0
11 1605.0 620.0 
12 1220.0 580.0
13 1465.0 200.0
14 1530.0 5.0
15 845.0 680.0
16 725.0 370.0
17 145.0 665.0
18 415.0 635.0
19 510.0 875.0  
20 560.0 365.0
21 300.0 465.0
22 520.0 585.0
23 480.0 415.0
24 835.0 625.0
25 975.0 580.0
26 1215.0 245.0
27 1320.0 315.0
28 1250.0 400.0
29 660.0 180.0
30 410.0 250.0
31 420.0 555.0
32 575.0 665.0
33 1150.0 1160.0
34 700.0 580.0
35 685.0 595.0
36 685.0 610.0
37 770.0 610.0
38 795.0 645.0
39 720.0 635.0
40 760.0 650.0
41 475.0 960.0
42 95.0 260.0
43 875.0 920.0
44 700.0 500.0
45 555.0 815.0
46 830.0 485.0
47 1170.0 65.0
48 830.0 610.0
49 605.0 625.0
50 595.0 360.0
51 1340.0 725.0
52 1740.0 245.0
EOF
```

I have tried to tweak the value of the parameters but it has never gone below or be `9000` it is always around the upper `9500` What can I improve to get it to work for my location file?

[image: Graph]

Comment: The easy thing to try is to reduce the mutation rate. As the population approaches the optimal solution, the random mutations can degrade the children as fast as the crossover improves the children, causing the population fitness to stagnate.

Comment: Large elites can be problematic because they can converge on a non-optimal solution and thereafter prevent better alternatives from gaining a foothold. This is particularly true if non-elites are thrown away at every iteration or totally excluded from crossover.

Comment: What does "Only max of 250000 fitness calculation is allowed" mean? Does it mean you are allowed to run up to gen 1249? If so, that is enough to solve the problem. As a side note, I ran your code 100 times without modification and 89% got below 9000 at gen 500, 99% at gen 1249.

Comment: you can try using `optuna`/`hyperopt` to optimize your  meta-parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything is fine tweaking the `distance` function and the `fit_proportionate_selection` ensures a faster run time which makes testing the  parameters faster. The other change is to have a fixed seed for the `random()` this way the results can be compared without much variant.

```
def fit_proportionate_selection(top_pop, elite_size):
    indices, fitness = zip(*top_pop)
    cumulative_sum = list(it.accumulate(fitness))
    total = cumulative_sum[-1]
    weights = [100*cs/total for cs in cumulative_sum]

    result = list(indices[:elite_size])
    
    for i in range(len(top_pop) - elite_size):
        select = random.randrange(100)
        for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
            if select <= weight:
                result.append(top_pop[i][0])
                break
    return result
```

Taken from my review question [Code review of the same code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284544/solving-the-travelling-salesman-problem-using-genetic-algorithm)

The parameters picked where from the comment of the review question:

```
pop_size = 150, elite_size=50, mutation_rate=0.0005, gen=400
```